# C# DialogBox and DialogResult

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to get the button of the DialogBox that the user clicked ... yet when I use the DialogResult I get this error

```
'System.Windows.Window.DialogResult' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'
```

How can I use the DialogResult??

Ok, I`ve managed to solve it.

```
MessageBoxResult Result = MessageBox.Show("Message Body", @"Caption/Title", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        switch (Result)
        {
            case MessageBoxResult.Yes:
                MessageBox.Show("Yes Pressed!!");
                break;
            case MessageBoxResult.No:
                MessageBox.Show("No Pressed!!");
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Can you add some source so we can see what you are doing specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: Just realised you're using WPF, not WinForms. Here's a correct implementation of DialogResult within WPF:

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
bool? dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog();
if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
{
   // User clicked OK
}
else
{
   // User clicked Cancel"
}
```

There's a good tutorial on it [here](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/05/28/wpf-dialogs-and-dialogresult/).

<s>Just sounds like you're using the Form's [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult.aspx) property incorrectly. You should be doing something like the following:</s>

```
DialogResult result = Form.DialogResult;
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
   // Do something
}
```

You can find the full `DialogResult` enumeration breakdown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: This is actually incorrect.  He's using WPF's (or Silverlight's) DialogResult property - this is for Windows Forms.  See the full name of the error message.

Comment: it didn`t work ... the type or namespace 'MyDialog' could not be found

Comment: MyDialog is just an example. You have to replace MyDialog with your Dialog/Class name.

Comment: I have found a solution and added it to my question.

Comment: @Sikas - maybe next time you'll tell us that you're using a MessageBox and show some example code of what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a DialogBox? Or would a MessageBox work for your purposes?

```
 DialogResult dlg = MessageBox.Show("Question User?",
                   "MessageBox Title",
                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                   MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (dlg == DialogResult.No)
            {
                //user changed mind. return
                return;
            }
```

etc.

Comment: I want a MessageBox to act upon user click, if the user clicks yes option1 performed, if no then option2 performed.

Comment: I have found a solution and added it to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to select the answer that helped you get there.

Answer (score 0):

DialogResult is Enum - you can directly compare with the DialogResult Property of your form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WPF or Silverlight then DialogResult is a bool? and you can use ?? to supply a value if the result is null.

```
if (myWindow.DialogResult ?? false)
    Debug.WriteLine("You clicked OK");
else
    Debug.WriteLine("You clicked Cancel");
```

Comment: I have found a solution and added it to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using WPF's `DialogResult` property, which is a `Nullable<bool>`, not an enumeration.

You need to check the result like so:

```
bool? dialogResult = dialogBox.ShowDialog();

if (dialogResult.HasValue) // Should always have a value, at this point, since the dialogBox.ShowDialog() returned at this point.  Will be false until the dialog is closed, however
{
    if (dialogResult.Value)
    {
        // User "accepted" the dialog, hitting yes, OK, etc...
    }
    else
    {
        // User hit "cancel" button
    }
}
```

Comment: I have found a solution and added it to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

C# DialogBox and DialogResult

```
    {

        DialogResult a1 = MessageBox.Show("Test", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (a1 == DialogResult.Yes)
            MessageBox.Show("Yes");
        else if (a1 == DialogResult.No)
            MessageBox.Show("No");

    }
```